# Cordova inappbrowser on ios only opens after leaving the app (home or recent apps view)

Tags: extjs, cordova, inappbrowser

I have an interesting problem with the Cordova InAppBrowser plugin on ios where it will only start working after I leave the app. For example, when I hit a button in the app that should load the InAppBrowser, nothing happens. I can wait 5 or 10 minutes and nothing will happen. If I double tap home and bring up the recent apps view, the InAppBrowser loads immediately. If I hit home then return to the app, it loads right away. After it loads the first time, it works immediately every subsequent time without having to leave the app.

I've confirmed this is what is happening with breakpoints on the init of the InAppBrowser view and view controller in xcode. They only get called after leaving the app.

The app is a Sencha-Touch app on the latest framework and the xcode project and plugins were generated/installed using the latest version of Cordova and from the command line. The only file i've modified in the project from that generated by Cordova (aside from my apps files in www) is the index.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <title>MyWebApp</title>

    <script>

        var Ext = Ext || {};

        Ext.theme = {

            name: "Default"

        };

    </script>

    <script src="sencha-touch-all.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/application.css">

    <script src="resources/js/currencyFormatter.js"></script>

    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have the same problem, but it only manifests itself once a YouTube video (iframe embed) has been loaded in the app. Really odd.

Comment: I am also suffering from the same issues, I've seen someone mention that hammer.js if you are using it seems to overwrite html5 drag and drop events so that event.datahandler never gets called until you move out of the app and back in again but I'm unsure if this is the same issue.  I'm currently using hammer.js for drag and drop functionality.